# How do I stop my scraper from hitting an error whenever it clicks the next button?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Hello so i'm trying to scrape next page on google shopping website. But i get an error whenever my scraper clicks the next button. It stops working when it loads the next page.

Here's my codeblock

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import pandas as pd




 url = 'https://www.google.com.ng/search?q=list+of+all+uk+e-commerce+stores+for+buying+prada+products&hl=en&biw=946&bih=625&tbm=lcl&sxsrf=ALiCzsaIKyYpvCJVWZx_fYTwSQerSvzC6g%3A1667482905673&ei=GcVjY4fUKJeG9u8PgvGwoAE&ved=0ahUKEwjHxIvykZL7AhUXg_0HHYI4DBQQ4dUDCAk&uact=5&oq=list+of+all+uk+e-commerce+stores+for+buying+prada+products&gs_lp=Eg1nd3Mtd2l6LWxvY2FsuAED-AEBMgUQABiiBDIHEAAYHhiiBDIFEAAYogQyBRAAGKIEwgIEECMYJ0iSHFDlBliOFHAAeADIAQCQAQCYAYYDoAHxDqoBBTItMS41iAYB&sclient=gws-wiz-local#rlfi=hd:;si:;mv:[[56.121909699999996,0.16756959999999999],[51.208233299999996,-4.5053765]]'

 service = Service(executable_path="C:/driver/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe")

 driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)

 driver.get(url)

 driver.maximize_window()

 time.sleep(8)



for i in range(7):    

   site_cards = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'uMdZh')
   time.sleep(4)

   site_list = []

   for card in site_cards:
      name = card.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'OSrXXb').text.strip()
      submit = card.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'OSrXXb')
      submit.click()
      time.sleep(4)
      try:
        more = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'Yy0acb').text.strip()
      except:
        print('none')
      try:
        more = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'mPcsfb').text.strip()
      except:
        print('none')
      time.sleep(2)
      try:
        more = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'YhemCb').text.strip()
      except:
        print('none')
      time.sleep(2)
      try:
        more = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'PQbOE').text.strip()
      except:
        print('none')
      try:
        more = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'Yy0acb').text.strip()
      except:
        print('none')
      try:
        more = driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'EvNWZc').text.strip()
      except:
        print('none')
      time.sleep(4)


      if ModuleNotFoundError:
        pass

      site_info = (name, more)
      site_list.append(site_info)

      col = ['Site Name', 'Site Link']
      df = pd.DataFrame([site_info], columns=col)
      df.to_csv("C:\\Users\LP\Documents\python\wedgwood\prada2.csv", index=False, encoding='utf-8', mode='a+')
```

next_page = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="pnnext"]')
next_page.click()

HERE'S THE ERROR I GET

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Users\LP\Documents\python\wedgwood\wedgwood.py", line 50, in 
name = card.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'OSrXXb').text.strip()

selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error means when it's looking for that element 'OSrXXb' it can't find it. You have a bunch of other elements wrapped in `try` blocks but it seems this one you expect to be there and it isn't.

Comment: Hi @Dean MacGregor, I was able to get the name  but couldn't get "Next_page". my code stops working whenever it hits the Next_page button. That's the problem. Any advice on how to continue scraping after hitting the Next Page button?

Comment: I used a "while True" statement and it worked. thanks guys